# Rating control in asp.net with database connectivity

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax, gridview, datatable

I have a .aspx page where i need to get the values from the data base and corresponding to the values i need a rating control for each entry. Also i need to store the rating.

Let me explain:

1) I have a table with a column 'col1' entries as "entry1,entry2"

2) I want the get the following data in another page in the following format
    For Eg:

```
 col1     col2

entry1    *****
entry2    *****
```

Where entry 1, entry2 is coming from the database and col2 is the rating control in asp.net

My question is how can i do it as the data is comma separated in the database and i want it one by one along with the rating control. Please help.

Comment: Ok so you need code right?

Comment: Yes, I mean , I want to know how to do it. Your help would be appreciable

Comment: Hi, why don't you just save the `Rating` together with the `Entry` information in a `database` so that you can just simply query it.